Slow `git fetch` operation on a repository using alternates
I'm looking to understand why a git fetch operation on a repository borrowing from an alternate object database (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#Documentation/gitrepository-layout.txt-objects) is very slow.
I have a local copy of some large git repository and I created a new clone with --reference pointing to the local copy that I already have. In the new clone, I am now trying to shallow fetch a single ref, for example git fetch --depth=1 origin <ref>, but I am finding that this is taking very long time to run compared to the initial clone I made with --reference. I would've expected it to be very fast if it's reusing the object database that I already have (similar to git clone --reference).
Can someone explain this behvior?
